# Django : Hellosignup callback url not coming to view

Tags: django, oauth, ngrok

I have registered a app at Hellosign and using locally for a django project.

While restringing the app it required the domain url for `OAuth` callbacks since i'm using the localhost, i have given a callback url genereated by https://ngrok.com/.

like: `https://1a2df3ef.ngrok.com/test/oauth`

Django oauth url mapping is like

```
url(r'^hellosign/oauth', 'hellosignup_oauth'),
```

view

```
def hellosignup_oauth(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    return render(request, 'hello.html', {'code': code})
```

On authorization, a request is made like

```
https://1a2df3ef.ngrok.com/test/oauth?&code=17c2264f2a24741c&state=900e06e2
```

and ngrok recives the request like

```
 hellosign/oauth
```

there seems to be two issues:

1) ngrok should receive request `hellosign/oauth?&code=17c2264f2a24741c&state=900e06e2` instead of `hellosign/oauth`.

2) `hellosign/oauth` view is not being called on  request `hellosign/oauth`

Any insight ?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be an issue, but it looks like you've got an empty URL parameter (i.e., "?&"). Could it be that Django is seeing the empty first parameter and dropping the 2nd?